# How Do I create class that can automaticly initialize other classes using String Parameters

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, types

I have the following problem:
I have a static Factory class and a bunch of Product Classes.
The Factory class should be given a bunch of String Vectors and be able to give back a Product Object as a BaseProductClass.

So I would basicly give the Factory class the Arguments "banana","green" and "fresh" and It would return a green Fresh Banana as a Product class.
The Problem I have is that the Factory class should not technicly know about all the Product classes and only know the Product base class. It should however have a Type array where all the Product classes are stored as generic Types assosciated with strings that identify them (Or the Strings are part of the class and can somehow be extracted).
It should just be able to take the first string argument, connect it to a type and then send this type the String array and let it initialize itself.

in the End I should be able to create new Product classes and just enter them into the generic typearray.
Does anyone know the most elegant method of realising something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your product classes needs to have it's own factory that, for example, is inherited from a `BaseProductFactory` class. This class declares a virtual `BaseProductClass *create()` method, for example, that's implemented in the subclass by constructing a new instance of that class.

Your "generic typearray" would map product name to pointers to the corresponding product class' `BaseProductFactory` instance.

You're essentially doing a type erasure on the factories, in addition to your product classes.

Comment: A bit dissapointing, I hoped there was a way to automate that using Templates or something that I could store in the Array. But your method sounds pretty good aswell, so thanks for that. Im gonna leve the question open for the moment, I hope thats okay

Comment: The factory subclass can be a template, of course, inheriting from the `BaseProductFactory` class.